# Visual studio not showing correct result after writing to repository

Tags: visual-studio, graph, load-testing, webtest

I recently got some issues with my load testing in visual studio. 
Everything works great with the test until the test finishes and visual studio are writing a report. Visual Studio is generating a report of the load test. It shows some false numbers and all the graphs are disappearing.
Everything worked great yesterday.

I've tried to repair visual studio, remake all the webtests and even create a new load test.

You can see some of the false data below in the picture.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8inie.png

Thanks for the help!

Comment: We need lots more information to try and help with this problem. What versions of all the relevant software (OS, SQL, VS , etc) are used? What do the system's log files and the Event Log show? What error messages are shown? What has been changed on the computer(s) between working ok and not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, when I splitthe two webtest to have 1 webtest as a initializer to login and one that would create a order. It bugged somehow on the login webtest. So after the test had finish and should collect all data it could not find the webtest that was initialized. I have not found a soulution yet but I know where to start digging.

Comment: A good start on understanding the problem. Can you please expand on the *"It bugged somehow on the login webtest"* sentence.